# Azure VM load balancing

Tags: azure, virtualhost

My client has a small Azure farm consisting of a domain controller, file server and, critically a Citrix XenApp server. It's run flawlessly for a couple of years.

They reported the XenApp server was offline this morning and when I checked Azure, there were indeed notifications that the host they were using had failed and the VM was being migrated to a new host. True to their word - and the core advantage of cloud computing - up comes the XenApp server on the new host and all is well. The ten users log back in to XenApp and carry on as if nothing had happened.

Until about 14:30 when they got in touch again saying XenApp was unresponsive. It took me about 10 minutes to logon. I've rebooted the XenApp VM but not made much difference.

Back when I managed a private cloud, I'd have logged onto the host to see how it was doing resource wise. Can one do this in Azure?

I'm assuming that Microsoft is running some kind of monitoring system that will identify when a host server is overloaded? Should we just wait this out and wait until the VM is load balanced? Or is that wishful thinking?

My client doesn't have any support contact with Microsoft so I hit a brick wall when I tried to raise a ticket. My client is understandably a bit miffed that he might have to pay to get a fix that, in his eyes, Microsoft have created. All a bit of a dark area of SLAs. Is there a way to raise a one off ticket?

Answer (score 1):

> Back when I managed a private cloud, I'd have logged onto the host to
>   see how it was doing resource wise. Can one do this in Azure?

No, you cannot log into the host of IaaS clouds like Azure. Rely on your application response time and VM level performance metrics.

Clouds like this also only do this host migration for hardware platform failures. You are on your own to provide HA at the application level.

If you wish to invest in faster service recovery, design for HA. For example, Citrix is capable of being load balanced across a Azure virtual machine scale set.

---

For the support case, Server Fault is not Azure. You must [contact Azure directly for support requests](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I suspected as much. One assumes that there is a SLA between my client and Microsoft that defines the level of service should expect but would imagine it's rather grey when it comes to performance. But it's going to be darn hard to ascertain the host performance is an issue without raising a ticket, for which you need at least a standard contract

Comment: Fortunately, performance today (so far) is much improved/back to normal - Microsoft must load balance VMs on each host separate to any HA we may have ourselves? Otherwise the hosts would become overloaded. Surely they must live migrate to other hosts if it becomes overloaded?

Comment: Finally, re XenApp HA - a comment well made. IMO they need to upgrade Citrix XenApp if not only because 6.5 is EOL but as a small company, XenApp is expensive up front. Parallels looks interesting for lower cost plus I've suggested they review Office 365. Very different cost models but they are currently very reliant on a very old single XenApp install which could corrupt itself/break at any time. The VM is updated by Azure each night in case of a bad upgrade/whatever

Comment: To do more than guess at what the underlying infrastructure is doing, engage as many performance and availability specialists as you can. For your platform, that means considering support engagements from the application developer, Citrix, and Microsoft.